# Setting up a mySQL parameter query in the designer

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, wampserver

I am trying set up a query in the dataset designer within Visual Studio 2017 using C#.

[image: Tables]

I am using WAMP as my DB server, when I execute the following from within wamp I get the expected results.

```
SELECT * FROM `product` NATURAL JOIN `contractproduct` WHERE ContractID = 1001
```

In fact, if I execute the exact same line from within Visual Studio's designer I get the same results. The problem is when I try to create a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` NATURAL JOIN `contractproduct` WHERE ContractID =@ID
```

VS gives me the error: "SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane." Even though I have used the =@VAR syntax for other queries. SQL is not my strong suit to begin with, but I really don't understand why it works in the designer's engine but then complains. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The answer is to use an inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN contractproduct c ON p.ProductID = c.ProductID
WHERE c.ContractID =@id
```

Comment: I don't know whether to delete this or leave it for someone else how may be as foolish as I was. Apparently, Visual Studio does not like Natural Joins. An inner join did the trick.

Comment: Natural joins are a bad practice, anyway.  A future table change that adds another column with a matching name can cause havoc.  Please post your answer as an actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this problem is to use an inner join.

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN contractproduct c ON p.ProductID = c.ProductID
WHERE c.ContractID =@id
```

This works perfectly in Visual Studio and as mentioned in a comment above, is a better practice than a natural join.